# Wordpress is running a function already removed

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

I've created a function to load CSS and JS in a file name my_functions.php 
after that I added like this

> add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','my_themes_styles');

And include this file from functions.php.

My problem now is whatever I update this function my_themes_styles are not effecting . I want to replace old css path with new and it's not working .

Sorry for my English and if question is not clear .

Comment: Are you using any cache plugin?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to change the css or script of admin side then use below action,

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'function_name' );

or if it is for front end side then your action is ok only check for,

wp_enqueue_style( string $handle, string $src = '', array $deps = array(), string|bool|null $ver = false, string $media = 'all' )

Answer (score 0):

I finally found that this my_functions.php was mistakenly uploaded under
Document root. After I removed this the my_functions.php is working back . 
I not very sure why this file was loaded instead of file under themes folder.